# How can I throw in sprites from both sides of the screen in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to apply a sort of impulse onto a sprite and have it thrown onto the screen from the side. However, when it is after the screen I want the impulse to stop and for the regular physics to be applied to it, so I would be able to drag it around. Its difficult to explain but if anyone can help out it would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give some more information or a drawing because i don't really get what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Apple docs show that a we can influence the `physicsBody` of a sprite with these instance methods:

```
- applyForce:
- applyTorque:
- applyForce:atPoint:
- applyImpulse:
- applyAngularImpulse:
- applyImpulse:atPoint:
```

As for "throwing it on the screen from the side", you can have the sprite spawn outside your current `skView`s bounds, and have the force be applied to it accordingly (if the sprite is located outside the north side of the screen, you'll want to `applyImpulse` downward).

With respect to "regular physics" upon entrance of the `skView`, you can have a check in `update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime` for those types of sprites entering the `skView`s frame OR define a protocol within your sprite's class, and have your `SKScene` subclass conform to that protocol; then have your sprite fire a method when entering a certain frame (`skView.frame`), which your `SKScene` will be able to respond to. You can then apply counter forces or impulses to that sprite.